# Error on setting up stun/turn server by restund

Tags: webrtc, stun

I followed the steps in http://nil.uniza.sk/sip/installing-and-configuring-restund-stunturn-server to set up a restund server.

When I test it by stun, the result is

```
STUN client version 0.96
Primary: Blocked or could not reach STUN server 
Return value is 0x00001c
```

Attached the config file

```
#
# restund.conf
#

# core
daemon          yes
debug           yes
realm           myrealm
syncinterval        600
udp_listen      192.168.1.25:3478
#udp_listen     1.2.3.4:3478
udp_sockbuf_size    524288
tcp_listen      192.168.1.25:3478
#tcp_listen     1.2.3.4:3478

# modules
module_path     /usr/local/lib/restund/modules
module          stat.so
module          binding.so
#module         auth.so
module          turn.so
#module         mysql_ser.so
module          syslog.so
module          status.so

# auth
auth_nonce_expiry   3600

# turn
turn_max_allocations    512
turn_max_lifetime   600
turn_relay_addr     192.168.1.25
#turn_relay_addr6   ::1

# mysql
#mysql_host     localhost
#mysql_user     ser
#mysql_pass     heslo
#mysql_db       ser
#mysql_ser      0

# syslog
syslog_facility     24

# status
#status_udp_addr        127.0.0.1
#status_udp_port        33000
status_http_addr    192.168.1.25
status_http_port    8080
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hosting your STUN/TURN server from behind a NAT. I'm guessing that from the looks of your conf file that lists 192.168.1.25 as the listening port.  If your client is from the outside of your NAT, make sure you have the proper port forwarding setup.

Otherwise, the most common case for this problem is that the host server has a firewall rule that blocks incoming traffic by default.  Check your firewall settings (iptables) on the host box as appropriate.

Comment: My client is the same machine as the server. And attached my iptables --list result.

Comment: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:3478 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:3478 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:3478 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:3478 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination